# pdf file is corrupted when a file encoded in base64 is downloaded

Tags: javascript, mysql

I try to download a pdf file that has been previously encoded using base 64.

I try to download it from an anchor tag, as follows

```
<a href="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUKJbXtrvsKMyAwIG9..." download="file.pdf">Download</a>;
```

The file is downloaded but when I try to open it I get a message that the file has damage or is corrupted.

Interestingly, if I change href to an encode image data, the file is downloaded and opened as expected.

I found this example http://jsfiddle.net/filixix/0816jdfq/ and I see that is changed from `data:application/pdf;base64,` to `data:application/octet-stream;base64`, I tried but I am getting the same result.

**Update**

I am encode the pdf file as follows

```
const element = document.querySelector('#file'); // input type file

element.addEventListener('change', handleChange);

function handleChange() {
    const file = this.files[0];
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = function() {
        const data = this.result;

        //  store data in database in a text type field
    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

hen, in the view where I want to download the file, I realize the logic that I commented

Comment: How do you know that it isn't corrupted or damaged to begin with?

Comment: the file I can check is ok

Comment: How did you verify the data is correct?

Comment: @user615274 can You put somewhere that pdf base64 content? I think that pdf is corrupted because of You keep it somewhere in db and it's being cut by size limits

Comment: And probably more importantly, how are you encoding the binary data to base64? Where and how are you assigning it to the `href` attribute?

Comment: I update the question in order to add more information

Comment: @user615274 ultimate solution: `keep it as binary data in file` (:

Comment: The problem is definitely in the "binary to b64" step, the download step don't even look at the mime type set in your dataURL's header. Please show where this step is performed. Also, if it is done server-side, prefer to send the binary file directly (if from same domain, just set the download attribute to the url pointing to the file), and if you generated that file on client side, then keep it as a Blob and use a blobURL instead of a dataURL.

Comment: `store data in database in a text type field` don't keep it in `text` type field, it has size limits, just use `LONGBLOB`

Comment: _"`//  store data in database in a text type field`"_  I'd say this is the problem. What database are you using? **Exactly** which data type is your text column?

Comment: database is mysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

General idea works as expected.

But I **recommend** You **to keep** pdf **as file**.

Cause Your **corrupted pdf issue** may be because of **db field size** (if You keep that string in db) or **browser's** request url **limitations**

So **You're** **saying**:

> store data in database in a text type field

If You don't plan to move to **file storage** just **change** field **type** to: `LONGBLOB`

Comment: `So encoding jpg or something to base64 and defining application/pdf does not make it pdf (:`. Could not have said it better myself.

Comment: change the data type of text the longblob solves the problem